# What is the distinction between sharing feedback and flagging here?

Tags: support, review-audits, review-suspension, specific-audit

I got smacked with another one of these:

[image]

I was going to leave a comment about needing to be more clear on the question (basically just give more details) and I got told this was the incorrect action. However, I'm not sure why this is an immediate "get your act together" compared to outright flagging the question. Can somebody lend some insight? Here is the question for those who need it:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/32815007

I've been suspended once again for a month now...please help me understand what I'm doing wrong. I spend a decent amount of time on each question and I feel like I get penalized for the tiniest infractions now:

[image]

Comment: Why do you think flagging was the correct option? That looks like a "known good" audit. The only correct response for the audit would have been "Looks OK". Related [Why did I fail this first question review audit after choosing sharing feedback?](/q/412271/15497888)

Comment: "I do not know how to fix" as a generic catch all to the problem, followed by less than instructive details below that should be more fleshed out. There is a flag specifically for needing details or clarity.

Comment: For https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/32694810 you said "Looks Ok", but it's clearly asking for a library, which is off-topic for [so].

Comment: I didnt say "Looks ok". I specifically wanted to share feedback that this question needed more details.

Comment: *"I've been suspended once again for a month now"* October 13 is 16 days away, not a month.

Comment: FWIW, the initial question you complain about *does* look like a bunch of gibberish. Even if one knows what it's about...

Comment: *"I didnt say "Looks ok""* [Check again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nrWe.png)

Comment: For the first question, I would probably have also left some feedback. A bunch of error messages (which are not in English) and no details which command/process produces the error messages is really not sufficient for SO.

Comment: @Larnu there has to be some error because I clearly remember this question having issues. Perhaps I selected the wrong option but seems odd.

Comment: Okay rereading this...does "share feedback" equate the same thing as "looks okay"? I know I didnt pass this one. It makes no sense.

Comment: I've never actually asked questions about the edits/audits here so I'm fairly in the dark about how this works.

Comment: *"does "share feedback" equate the same thing as "looks okay""* No, the reason you failed the audit you originally asked about is covered by the first [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420557/what-is-the-distinction-between-sharing-feedback-and-flagging-here?noredirect=1#comment928238_420557): *" The only correct response for the audit would have been "Looks OK""*

Comment: [...what is with this "edit" header on the first revision of this post that's existed for less than half an hour](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/420557/1)

Comment: I got suspended after doing this edit which i thought was related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How long did you *actually* take to process this question?

Not going to lie, at first it does look like there's some kind of issue with it, but if you slow down a *whole* lot, then you'll start to tease some things out.

First, there's this line.

> assinaturas eram inválidas

Okay, that's obviously not English, but if you look at it in context...

> assinaturas eram inválidas: EXPKEYSIG C99B11DEB97541F0 Nate Smith vilmibm@github.com

...then you get something that *kinda* looks like a GPG error of some sort.

So then...has this kind of error cropped up before somewhere?  Well yeah, but you'd be easily forgiven if you couldn't tell what the actual problem was just by searching on the above string.  Lots and lots of results come back in Portuguese.

So...if you then *translate* key part, you get this back.

> signatures were invalid

Okay then, so we're talking about a GPG error in which the signature was invalid for a given and provided key.

Let's pull more context into the question then.

From the first part of their question, they're getting some kind of warning when attempting to access a Git repository.

> W: Falhou ao obter https://cli.github.com/packages/dists/stable/InRelease: As seguintes

So then what we can surmise is that this question is being asked by someone who operates their computer in Portuguese (dialect gently set aside here) who is having trouble accessing a Git repository because of an invalid GPG signature.

...

---

Not going to lie, but this is a *terrible* audit.  You had to do a lot of jumping through hoops to figure this one out, and your average reviewer in a hurry could be forgiven for thinking that this question doesn't make a lot of sense.  That's because...it really didn't until you took more time to break things down.

So you get a pass on *this* one, IMO.  The others?  Well, you should slow down a bit more and review a bit more patiently.  I can't speak to the others in as much detail, mostly because you put a picture of links instead of links and I've got other things to do besides try to derive the links in those pictures and audit your audits.

Comment: "Share feedback" was okay IMO. The question is essentially: "I get the following error: <error_message>" Although an experienced eye might see the problem, the question _could_ use some details, for example: "I was trying to install GitHub CLI by following <instructions> but got the following error when running `sudo apt update`: <error_message>"

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat:  No, commenting is *seldom* a good idea on any question.  Usually if there's something wrong with the question, downvoting or voting to close are *orders* more effective to address the actual problem as opposed to commentating.  You can't guarantee if the person is still around to care about their question, but the system can still rank it if it's voted on appropriately.

Comment: I agree on that part, and that is what I do myself (voting to close + a comment if appropriate) I would say the problem is that the queue unnecessarily duplicates actions a user can take ("Question is unclear" is one of the options under "Share feedback").

Comment: I note that the question is now closed. It should be; despite the popularity and voting, it's unclear and lacks an MRE or even really any context. You have to guess that OP was... trying to get something... ? from the repository? And after that it comes across as more of a question about how the internet works and what certificates are, rather than anything about programming. If this error came up on a general website rather than GitHub, the question would be clearly off topic; and there's nothing clearly *particular to using GitHub* that causes the error.

Comment: Granted, yes, we accept certain questions about tools, against my personal ideals for the site. But even then it's a bad question.

Comment: "Not going to lie, but this is a terrible audit." It's a terrible *question*. Using it as an audit is just wrong, even if it is understandable that the algorithm cannot tell that. You shouldn't have to jump through so many hoops to understand an audit *because you shouldn't have to jump through so many hoops to understand a question*.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel:  I'll remind you that Git and GitHub are both tools that a developer uses, and thus would be on-topic for the site.  The *only* reason that this question should be closed - and it's reason enough - is that it's just unclear.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi:  A terrible audit came from a terrible question, and I totally agree with your characterization (and I think the point I was making on the audit got through to you with that). :)

Comment: I understand the reasoning and the guidelines for topicality. I just *disagree with them*. This is not an attempt to advocate for policy change, just a principled grumbling.